# C++ connect with just sockaddr, no sockaddr_in, how?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

void socktry_fnc(){

    void *buf;

    inet_pton (AF_INET, "192.168.1.100", buf);

    printf ("%c\n", (char *)buf);
}
```

Segmentation fault

What is the problem?

Comment: Try allocating space for the buffer: `char buf[sizeof(struct in6_addr)];`

Answer (score 0):

Formally, you have undefined behavior because you read (formally, caused "lvalue to rvalue conversion" to take place) from an uninitialized variable (`buf`, the read occurs when passing parameters to `inet_pton`).

Johnny's comment shows a solution.